# How to open a modal based on the hashtag in the URL using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open a module when the url has a certain hashtag. But nothing seems to happen when I add a hashtag to my url. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
<div id="overlay">
     <div class="howlModal">
          <iframe width="300" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UP34u6rdscs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.howlModal').hide();

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    switch(hash) {
    case '#howl':
        $('howlModal').show();
        break;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you put the hash in the url and hit enter the page will not reload, did you try to paste your url WITH the hash in a new browser tab or reload the page with ctrl-r (on chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.howlModal').hide();

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    switch(hash) {
    case '#howl':
        $('.howlModal').show();
        break;
    }
});
```

**$('.howlModal').show();** **not $('howlModal').show();**

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work for me however. I'm trying to get it to do something like this: http://www.chicagobooth.edu/programs/full-time/profiles/#Sara1